# How can I get sqlite3 to stop failing on insert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, insert

```
for k,v in account.items():
    try:
        connection.execute('''
        INSERT INTO my_acct
        (acct_name, acct_username, acct_password, created_date, category_id)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ''', (k, v[0], v[1] , datetime('now'), 1))
        print('\nINSERTED!!!\n')             
    except:
        print('Error Occurred inserting')
```

When I run, it outputs the `except:` block instructions

I took off the try: except: and the datetime('now') is throwing this error:

```
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ''', (k, v[0], v[1] , datetime('now'), 1))
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `datetime.now()`, instead of `datetime('now')`. But please make sure to import it first.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now()
```

Comment: You know, I was able to figure this out on my own, but you definitely validated it. Thank you so much!